# Calling an angularjs function during controller init

Tags: angularjs, checkbox, angularjs-view

I have a large amount of code that I inherited. It is working according to the original spec, so although it may or may not be the "right" way of doing things, it does work and I'd prefer not to mess with it. (I am VERY new to angular, and under a tight deadline - I don't have time right now to "fix" things that aren't broken, even if they're not being done the "correct" way.)

I have a checkbox and a group of address fields. When the checkbox is checked, a function runs that populates the address fields.

```
<input id='as_check' type="checkbox" ng-model='model.prepop_addr' ng-change="model.handlePrepopAddress()">
<input type="text" placeholder="Address 1" required ng-model='model.payment.addr1'/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Address 2" ng-model='model.payment.addr2'/>
<input type="text" placeholder="City" required ng-model='model.payment.city'/>
<input type="text" placeholder="State" required ng-model='model.payment.state'/>
<input type="text" placeholder="Zip" required ng-model='model.payment.zip'/>
```

In my controller, I have a function called `handlePrepopAddress()`:

```
model.handlePrepopAddress = function () {
        if (model.prepop_addr) {
            console.log("prepop is true");
            var del_addr = $window.user_state.deliveryAddress;

            model.payment.addr1 = del_addr.address;
            model.payment.addr2 = null;
            model.payment.city = del_addr.city;
            model.payment.state = del_addr.state;
            model.payment.zip = del_addr.zip;
        } else {
            console.log("prepop is false");
            model.payment.addr1 = null;
            model.payment.addr2 = null;
            model.payment.city = null;
            model.payment.state = null;
            if (!model.payment.saved) {
                model.payment.zip = null;
            }
        }

        return true;
    };
```

When I click the checkbox, this runs correctly and updates the various fields. Requirements have changed, and the client now wants the checkbox defaulted to checked, which would then default the values of the fields. Rather than duplicating code, I thought I'd be able to just run the function at the start of the controller, like this:

```
place_order.controller('AsCreditCardCtrl', ['$scope', 'PaymentModel', function ($scope, model) {
    $scope.model = model;
    model.prepop_addr = true;
    model.handlePrepopAddress();
}]);
```

The function is running, as the `console.log` statements I have in the function are running. But the view is not updating; the checkbox is visibly unchecked and the fields are empty aside from the initial placeholder values.

What am I missing? How can I make the function update the view?

Comment: I guess you could just check the checkbox with jquery $('#as_check').prop('checked', true); Feels a lil wrong though. What about setting "checked" in the html?

Comment: Yeah, you're really not supposed to mix jquery and angular. Just setting checked in the html doesn't work; something is overwriting it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var i=  model.handlePrepopAddress();
```

It might work.